Finding longest substring u of w such that uuu is a substring in w
Given a string w, how do I find the longest substring u such that uuu is contained in w?
I can compute the suffix array and corresponding LCP array of w reasonably fast in python. I tried to get the solution of my problem going from there, but all I managed to do was to get the longest substring that is repeated at least 3 times. I tried to check if the these strings I got there are adjacent but it didn't work out sadly.

Sorry, but asking questions here really does not work this way. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide some code of what you had tried.

It feels like you're just asking us to write this code for you.  We don't really do that here.

The question looks fine to me. Minimal reproducible examples are for debugging questions, and this isn't a debugging question. They're trying to find an algorithm to solve a problem, and they've told us algorithmic approaches they've tried (actually a pretty solid effort!).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have done a little programming but I am not very good at Python.  This sounds like an interesting exercise.  If I could see what you have so far, I would be interested in seeing about extending it to do what you need.

@user2357112 This looks like a coding challenge problem. The whole point of these is for the user to figure the algorithm out themselves.

@Barmar There is nothing wrong with asking about how to solve it if they are stuck.

@Unmitigated Sure, but since they said they made an attempt that doesn't work, they should post that code so we can explain what they did wrong and how to fix it.

@Barmar The main issue is they have the wrong algorithm. In general, such a failed attempt is not very useful to see; usually you can just ignore it and post a correct algorithm. It is not like a simple programming problem where the failed attempt can be trivially fixed, so a description of the algorithm tried tends to suffice.

Can you share anything about the input? I.e., is it a random string of letters (so 'z' and 'x' are as likely as 'a' and 'e'), or would the distribution look more like English or some other language? How long is the input likely to be? If this problem is available in its original form, could you append the exact problem to your question?

@Dave: Do you have an answer that depends on those things?

@Ry Any detail may inform an answer, and people asking for help with algorithm questions, through no fault of their own, sometimes omit important details that they don't recognize as important.

@Dave: Okay, but there are already correct, efficient answers and there’s a limit to the value of “any” detail. A link to the original problem would certainly be nice, though, yes.

Naive approach: To get longest substring that repeats 3 times is basically checking for adjacent indices which contains the same string right? Then build a dictionary with key as string and value as list of pair of indices which are adjacent and whenever the list size is 3, get the maximum length of string that you could get. If the current value in the list is not adjacent just start afresh for that key.
Complexity is O(n^2) though.
def get_longest(s, repeat):
    d = {}
    L = len(s)
    max_str = ""
    max_len = 0
    for i in range(0, L):
        for j in range(i, L):
            t = s[i:j+1]
            if not t in d:
                d[t] = []
                d[t].append([i,j])
            else:
                idx = d[t][-1]
                if idx[1] != i-1:
                    d[t] = []
                d[t].append([i,j])
            if len(d[t]) == repeat and len(t) > max_len:
                max_len = len(t)
                max_str = t

    return max_str


print(get_longest("abcbcdefghghgh", 3))

Output:
gh

Let me know if I m missing anything here.

For inspiration: look at algorithms for finding repetitions (tandem repeats) - Main-Lorentz, Crochemore, Landau-Schmidt.
If you have tandem repeat at position l of size s, check also tandem at l + s of the same size.
If z-function is used (as in M-L algo), then z-array contains value s at positions s and 2*s for given l beginning.

I don't think this is the most efficient way but since your initial effort is the first step of the following algorithm, I felt this answer was a nice addition.
Using a suffix tree, you can get the set of substrings repeated at least 3 times.
Since the substring we are looking for is repeated, it will necessary lead to branching in the suffix tree. Moreover, we're only interested in the longest such substring and thus we can focus on the internal nodes of the tree.
To do so, begin by building the tree. Then compute the number of children of each node and stash those with 3+ children in a max heap according to the length of the substring represented by the node.
Pseudo code for the algorithm looks like this:
def stash_substring(Node, NodeQueue):
    // ChildCount will be the number of leaves in the subtree rooted at Node.
    LeafCount = 0
    // MaxLen will be the maximum length of the subtree rooted at Node
    MaxLen = Node.Substring().len()
    for Child in Node.Children():
        count, len = stash_substring(Child, NodeQueue)
        LeafCount = ChildCount + count
        MaxLen = max(MaxLen, len)

    if LeafCount >= 3 and 3*Node.Substring().len() <= MaxLen:
        NodeQueue.push((Node, Node.Substring())
    if LeafCount == 0: // Leaf
        LeafCount = 1
    return ChildCount, MaxLen

Now for each such (Node, Node.Substring()) pair, you have to walk down the tree, starting at Node using Node.Substring() twice. As soon as there is a mismatch you can dump the current substring and proceed to the next. The first you find is the longest one!

Another possibility. And since we're looking for the longest repeating substring, let's search for the longest first, so as soon as we find one solution we can return it, no need for memorization of previous results.
def get_longest_repeating(s, rpt):
    max_len = len(s) // rpt
    for x_len in range(max_len, 0, -1):
        for start in range(len(s) - x_len * rpt + 1):
            for check in range(start + x_len, start + x_len * rpt, x_len):
                if s[start:start+x_len] != s[check:check+x_len]:
                    break
            else:
                return s[start:start+x_len]
    return False

